# elasticsearch aliases manipulation with jq

Tags: elasticsearch, jq

I'm kinda loosing my hair over this one so maybe you can help
I need to manipulate elasticsearch output with jq to get a valid json that i can add to ES later on.

what i have is:

```
{
  "testindex_123": {
    "aliases": {
      "testindex": {}
    }
  },
  "testindex_122": {
    "aliases": {
      "testindex": {}
    }
  }
}
```

and i want to create a script/run jq on that so it would produce

```
{
    "actions" : [
    {
        "add" : {
        "index" : "testindex_122",
        "alias" : "testindex",
        "is_write_index": false
        }
    },
    {
        "add" : {
        "index" : "testindex_123",
        "alias" : "testindex",
        "is_write_index": true
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

And why? I'm setting up elasticsearch snapshot&restore workflow that would leave aliases and once reindex/restore is complete replace the indices based on epoch time so in this example

```
testindex_122
```

will get replaced with

```
testindex_123
```

while testindex alias will be active.
It seems doable but i really have no idea how to set this up :/

any pointers would be great
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand where the boolean value should come from, but the rest could be generated by:

```bash
{actions: to_entries | map({add: {
  index: .key,
  alias: .value.aliases | keys[],
  is_write_index: true
}})}
```

```json
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "testindex_123",
        "alias": "testindex",
        "is_write_index": true
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "testindex_122",
        "alias": "testindex",
        "is_write_index": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/M6Ma0rza-rn)

---

Addressing the boolean values, OP clarified:

> is it possible for boolean to come from higher number? for instance i will always want to restore from date in the future. so in that case 123 > 122therefore 122== false 123 == true. Does that make any sense?

Store the maximum of those values in a variable, and while iterating, compare the current one to it:

```bash
def keynum: (.key / "_")[-1] | tonumber;

{actions: (to_entries | (map(keynum) | max) as $max | map({add: {
  index: .key,
  alias: .value.aliases | keys[],
  is_write_index: (keynum == $max)
}}))}
```

```json
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "testindex_123",
        "alias": "testindex",
        "is_write_index": true
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "testindex_122",
        "alias": "testindex",
        "is_write_index": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/enqronfQpmF)

Comment: is it possible for boolean to come from higher number? for instance i will always want to restore from date in the future. so in that case 123 > 122therefore 122== false 123 == true. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @user19692907 I have updated the response with setting the third field to `true` for the highest of all numbers extracted from after the underscore `_` from the first field, and `false` otherwise.